# call subprocess python with no spaces

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

Considering one variable "outdir", included in the command line to create a directory where I will deposit my outputs, what is the best option to call a subprocess that only accept the parameters like "-o=both" and do not permit spaces between the parameter (-d=) and the value (outdir)?

`'-o=both','-m=both' and '-t=4'` can be established before and I have it already included in my script.

This is the line that I used:

```
subprocess.call(['external_script.pl', '-d=',outdir,'-o=both','-m=both','-t=4'])
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused what you are asking. You could avoid the spaces by passing ``outdir.strip()`` or check with a ``if`` statement before subprocess if there are spaces at the start of ``outdir``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just putting your parameter as you need:

['external_script.pl', '-d=%s' % outdir,'-o=both','-m=both','-t=4']

Answer (score 0):

I changed the ',' for a '+' in the line and it worked.

```
subprocess.call(['external_script.pl', '-d='+outdir,'-o=both','-m=both','-t=4'])
```